# JSON multi-value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i need help parsing the following:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "Function": "Administration",
      "SubFunction": "Facilities,Maintnce,Bldg Svcs,Other,Secretary"
    },
    {
      "Function": "Communications",
      "SubFunction": "Internal Communications,Marketing Comm,Other"
    },
    {
      "Function": "Customer_Services",
      "SubFunction": "Customer Engineer,Dispatcher,NonQuota Acct Supp Mgr,Other,PreSales-Network,Process and Systems,Quota Acct Supp Mgr,Remote Support Services,Rework,Service Offer Development,Services Logistics,Services Planning,Technology Consultant"
    }
  ]
}
```

My jQuery code is:

```
                $select3.html('');
                $select4.html('');
                $.each(data.data, function(key, val){
                  $select3.append('<option id="' + val.Function + '">' + val.Function + '</option>');
                  $.each(this.SubFunction, function(){
                    $select4.append('<option id="' + val.SubFunction + '">' + val.SubFunction + '</option>');
                    })
                })
```

**What should happen:** The first option box should be filled with the "Function" and the second with the "SubFunction" upon the "Function" selection.

**What is happening:** The first option box does load up the "Function" values correctly, but the second drop down has all of the "Subfunction" from all "Function" with multiple instances of them.

Please help.

Thank You.

Comment: Are you trying to parse SubFunction value to create an array from it to add each word (like 'Facilities', 'Maintnce' and etc.) as a separate <option>?

Comment: You'll need a `change` event handler, so that the second dropdown values can be replaced whenever the first dropdown is changed. You'll also need to split the `SubFunction` string into separate values. I'll put together an answer if I get a chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/b2cto3bd/1/)

Here is how to do it. You could use a `data attribute` to store the options for each function in the the `option` elements of `select3`, then when each of these options is selected, the value in the data attribute is read and parsed and used to populate `select4` on-the-fly.

```
$select3.empty();
$.each(data.data, function(key, val){
    $select3.append(
        $('<option/>',{id:val.Function,text:val.Function,'data-sub-function':val.SubFunction})
    );        
});

$(function() {
    $select3.on('change',function() {
        $select4.empty();
        $.each($('option:selected', this).data('sub-function').split(','), function(i,val){
            $select4.append(
                $('<option/>', {id:val,text:val})
            );
        });
    })
    .change();
});
```

Comment: I get a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined"

Comment: My bad! please see correction above ... changed `$(this)` to `$('option:selected', this)`. It should work now ... will add `.change()` so it will populate by default too.

Comment: Works now, but i still get the same error. Which i believe breaks it in IE.

Comment: By *same error* do you mean the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined`? How is that possible?

Comment: Yes, on this line:  $.each($('option:selected', this).data('sub-function').split(','), function(i,val){

Comment: Works for me -- IE 11. Can you share your code above as an update? For continuity, just append the updated code to the current question.

Comment: For mine, i am calling the json data from url, would the "this" make a difference?

Comment: Let me take a quick look at your code to see what suggestions I can make.

Comment: I have put my suggestions [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/z64cuokx/4/) ... just make sure `baseUrl` is defined.

Comment: baseUrl is defined earlier in the page so its not the problem. Was anything else changed?

Comment: Noticed the change. The new function, breaks the rest of the other things on the page. :/

Comment: Not sure I understand. You may want to share a link to your live page.

Comment: Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/xntcprqd/ Tried everything, still getting that error.

Comment: Everything looks fine to me. Please provide a URL to your live page.

Comment: Its on an intranet server. So no outside access. :/

Comment: Is the error only occurring in IE? What version? Using this code may prevent (not solve) the error: $select4.empty();
                        var sf = $('option:selected', this).data('sub-function'),
                            options = sf ? sf.split(',') : [];
      $.each(options, function(i, val){

Comment: IE9. That fixed half the issue. Now, the SubFunctions all load on one line in the select4 input when you select a Function. But when you drop down, you can select them individually. I def owe you beer after this. lol.

Answer (score 3):

You need a change handler for this. This should do the job:

```js
$select3 = $('#select3');
$select4 = $('#select4');
$.each(data.data, function() {
    addOption($select3, this.Function);
});

$.each(data.data[0].SubFunction.split(','), function() {
    addOption($select4, this);
});

$select3.on('change', function() {
    $select4.html('');

    $.each(data.data, function() {
        if ($select3.val() === this.Function) {
            $.each(this.SubFunction.split(','), function() {
                addOption($select4, this);
            });
        }
    });
});

function addOption($target, value) {
    $target.append('<option id="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m88u76eL/

Comment: For some reason it only works for the first "Function". After selecting another "Function" like "Communications" there is no drop down for select4.

Comment: Hmm, it works fine for me. When I pick a "Function", $select4 is updated accordingly.

Comment: Not on jsfiddle. After adding it to my code. Thats what happens for some reason. Shouldnt have anything to do with the json file being called and not in the same file should it? Thank you.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this can only happen if `$select3.val() === this.Function` never returns true. Maybe this helps as a pointer!

Comment: Hey Martin, could you help with this please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26243873/jquery-json-form-is-only-sending-pre-poluated-values

Answer (score 0):

You are already looping in data Object why are you doing a extra $.each ?

```
                $select3.html('');
                $select4.html('');
                $.each(data.data, function(key, val){
                  $select3.append('<option id="' + val.Function + '">' + val.Function + '</option>');

                    $select4.append('<option id="' + val.SubFunction + '">' + val.SubFunction + '</option>');

                });
```

This just work just find? Not tested tho just a quick post to help out

Comment: What he wants is to have 2 select boxes. First one has all 'Function' properties. Upon selection of an option in the Functions selectbox, a second dropdown should get populated with all its 'SubFunctions'