# jQuery JSON Form is only sending Pre-Poluated Values

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a form. I have pre-populated the values using JSON/Web Service.

Ex:

```
                    <tr id="">
                        <td class="tleft">
                            <label for="nickname" class="fieldLabel"><span class="ui-small-text">Nick Name:</span></label> 
                        </td class="tright">
                        <td class="tright">
                           <input name="nickname" type="text"  class="nickname" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

Populated Using:

```
            $(".nickname").val(person.nickname);
```

I am sending the form back to another URL using JSON. I verified that works by using a hidden field that isnt populated to see if its updating, but for some reason, all fields being populated, when changed on the screen, still send the same values they were populated with.

**Full Code:** http://pastebin.com/F3dt8ncC

Thank You.

Comment: Post your full code.  I don't even see a 'person' object, that makes it pretty hard to debug.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/F3dt8ncC

Comment: Your link seems to be pointing to a removed paste.

Comment: Fixed the issue. Thanks Martin!